# Autofac property injection is not working

Tags: autofac

i am trying to use autofac for prism. Used bootstraper project link is bellow. autofac is passes depened object when i used as contructor parameter. but it's not passes when i use as property with a import attribute.

https://bitbucket.org/stmu/prism.aufofacextension/src

it's not a prism question. autofac is not inject properties. what is my mistake? how to solve this? thanks.

Comment: can you add a minimal example of a class where the property injection does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `RegisterType` calls, you most likely need to add `.PropertiesAutowired()`.